# Most love serve games

Tags: tennis, records, atp, wta

What is the record for the most love serve games in a tennis match for men and women?

In tennis the word love is used to represent 0 points in a game. So by love serve game, I mean a server game won without dropping a single point.

Comment: Possibly a good place to start: [Longest tennis match records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_tennis_match_records#Overall). Personally, I'm going to guess Isner-Marut just based on the sheer number of games played.

Comment: and also long matches like Isner - Mahut are long in large part because both players are winning their service games consistently.  This indicates both are probably serving well/returning badly and so have decent odds of having a higher rate of holding for love than other matches.